# how to show image in javascript coming from laravel controller in json form

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have coming images in data
my code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

    $('.show-btn').click(function() {
        var pid = $(this).data("id");
        //alert(pid);
         $.ajax({
               type:'get',
               url:'home/dataajex/'+pid,
               dataType:"json",
               success:function(data) { 
               data.forEach(function(element) {  
                    var imgSource = document.getElementById('data').src ;

                    document.body.appendChild(load_data); 
                    console.log(imgSource);     
                });
                console.log(data);

               }
            });                      
    });
});
```

how can i show images in it 
my html div id is load_data

Comment: where `load_data` come from ? you didn't use it before.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$.ajax({
           type:'get',
           url:'home/dataajex/'+pid,
           dataType:"json",
           success:function(data) { 

             $.each(data, function(index) {
                 $('#yourDivId').append("<img src='"+data[index]+"'>");
             }

           }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.show-btn').click(function() {
    var pid = $(this).data("id");
    //alert(pid);
     $.ajax({
           type:'get',
           url:'home/dataajex/'+pid,
           dataType:"json",
           success:function(data) { 
           data.forEach(function(element) {  
                //var imgSource = document.getElementById('data').src ;
                var img = element.imagepath; // get image path
                $('#data').attr('src',img);
               // document.body.appendChild(load_data); 
               // console.log(imgSource);     
            });
            console.log(data);

           }
        });                      
});
```